# Is this the correct formatting

Tags: python

My goal is to find out whether this is the correct formatting to find out the class type returns the data type class of the variable

My expected result was to see `<class 'float'>` but I got this

This is the code which I typed in to get the result `<class 'float'>` but got the error `print(float(type(a)))`

this is the number I assigned to variable `a`

```
a*=2
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Webucator\assignment_operators.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(float(type(a)))

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'type'
```

Comment: What do you expect `float(type(a))`  to return?

Comment: I expect it to return ```<class 'float '>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the order of functions reversed.

The [`type(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function returns the passed object's type, which in Python is another object, called a [Type Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-type-objects). Printing the Type Object gives you something like `<class 'int'>` or `<class 'float'>` depending on the object.

The [`float(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) returns the floating point number from a *string* or a *number*. You cannot pass a Type Object to `float`, so you cannot do `float(type(a))`.

You need to `float(a)` first before `type()`.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a*=2
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> float(a)
2.0
>>> type(float(a))
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(type(a))
```

outputs:

```
<class 'float'>
```

You don't need to call float

Comment: I have just edited my question about the variable assigned to "a"

Comment: I need to call float

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the way you have done!
You are passing type as an argument, in Python just by passing number or its string form as argument, you will get your answer.
Just do:

```
>>> a = float(a)
>>> type(a)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: I have just edited my question about the variable assigned to "a"

Comment: Yes, still it will work, so if ```a=3``` and you did ```a*=2``` then we have a=6. If you do ```print(a)``` you will get 6. Then follow the steps in the answer.